# boost spirit istream_iterator consumes too much from stream

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

Consider the following example extracted from a more complex code:

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/std_pair.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/support_istream_iterator.hpp>
#include <map>
#include <string>

namespace qi  = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phx = boost::phoenix;

// The class implements a XML tag storing the name and a variable number of attributes:
struct Tag
{
    // The typedef defines the type used for a XML name:
    typedef std::string name_type;

    // The typedef defines the type used for a XML value:
    typedef std::string value_type;

    // The typedef defines the type of a XML attribute:
    typedef std::pair<
        name_type,
        value_type
    > attribute_type;

    // The type defines a list of attributes.
    // Note: We use a std::map to simplify the attribute search.
    typedef std::map<
        name_type,
        value_type
    > list_type;

    // Clear all information stored within the instance:
    void clear( )
    {
        m_name.clear( ); m_attribute.clear( );
    }

    std::size_t m_indent;    // The tag shall be / is indented by m_indent number of tabs.
    name_type   m_name;      // Name of the tag.
    list_type   m_attribute; // List of tag attributes.
};

// Define the mapping between Tools::Serialization::Archive::Type::Xml::Format::Tag and boost::fusion:
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT( Tag,
                         ( std::size_t   , m_indent    )
                         ( Tag::name_type, m_name      )
                         ( Tag::list_type, m_attribute ) )

// This class implements the decoder skipper grammar:
template < typename _Iterator >
    struct skipper
    : qi::grammar< _Iterator >
    {
        skipper( ) : skipper::base_type( m_skipper )
        {
            // The rule defines the default skipper grammar:
            m_skipper = ( qi::space )  // Skip all "spaces".
                        |
                        ( qi::cntrl ); // Skip all "cntrl".
        }

        // The following variables define the rules used within this grammar:
        qi::rule< _Iterator > m_skipper;
    };

// This class implements the grammar used to parse a XML "begin tag".
// The expected format is as follows: <name a="xyz" b="xyz" ... N="xyz">
template < typename _Iterator, typename _Skipper >
    struct tag_begin : qi::grammar< _Iterator, Tag( ), _Skipper >
    {
        tag_begin( ) : tag_begin::base_type( m_tag )
        {
            // The rule for a XML name shall stop when a ' ' or '>' is detected:
            m_string = qi::lexeme[ *( qi::char_( "a-zA-Z0-9_.:" ) ) ];

            // The rule for a XML attribute shall parse the following format: 'name="value"':
            m_attribute =    m_string
                          >> "=\""
                          >> m_string
                          >> '"';

            // The rule for an XML attribute list is a sequence of attributes separated by ' ':
            m_list = *( m_attribute - '>' );

            // Finally the resulting XML tag has the following format: <name a="xyz" b="xyz" ... N="xyz">
            m_tag =     '<'
                     >> -qi::int_
                     >> m_string
                     >> m_list
                     >> '>';

            // Enable debug support for the used rules. To activate the debug output define macro BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG:
            BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES( ( m_string )( m_attribute )( m_list ) )
        }

    // The following variables define the rules used within this grammar:
    qi::rule< _Iterator, Tag::name_type( )     , _Skipper > m_string;
    qi::rule< _Iterator, Tag::attribute_type( ), _Skipper > m_attribute;
    qi::rule< _Iterator, Tag::list_type( )     , _Skipper > m_list;
    qi::rule< _Iterator, Tag( )                , _Skipper > m_tag;
};

bool beginTag( std::istream& stream, Tag& tag )
{
    // Ensure that no whitespace characters are skipped:
    stream.unsetf( std::ios::skipws );

    // Create begin and end iterator for given stream:
    boost::spirit::istream_iterator begin( stream );
    boost::spirit::istream_iterator end;

    // Define the grammar skipper type:
    typedef skipper<
        boost::spirit::istream_iterator
    > skipper_type;

    // Create an instance of the used skipper:
    skipper_type sk;

    // Create an instance of the used grammar:
    tag_begin<
        boost::spirit::istream_iterator,
        skipper_type
    > gr;

    // Try to parse the data stored within the stream according the grammar and store the result in the tag variable:
    bool r = boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parse( begin,
                                              end,
                                              gr,
                                              sk,
                                              tag );

    char nextSym = 0;
    stream >> nextSym;

    for( auto i = tag.m_attribute.begin( ); i != tag.m_attribute.end( ); ++i )
    {
        std::cout << i->first << " : " << i->second << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Next symbol: " << nextSym << std::endl;

    return r;
}

int main( )
{
    std::stringstream s;
    s << "<object cName=\"bool\" cVersion=\"1\" vName=\"bool\">       <value>0</value></object>";

    Tag t;
    beginTag( s, t );

    return 0;
}
```

I use the grammar to extract the xml tag content. In principle this works as expected and the results are as follows:

```
cName : bool
cVersion : 1
vName : bool
Next symbol: v
```

The problem is that the parser consumes to much data. My expectation is that the parser stops when first tag is closed '>'. But it seems that the parser consumes also the following spaces and the '<' symbol. So the next symbol read from the stream is equal to 'v'. I would like to avoid this because following parser calls expect the '<' symbol. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no reliable way to achieve this.

The problem is you're not re-using the `istream_iterator`s across parse calls. The whole purpose for `boost::spirit::istream_iterator` is provide a `multi_pass` capable iterator on top of an InputIterator¹.

Because Spirit allows arbitrary grammars with arbitrary backtracking, you cannot prevent consuming more than the input that was actually *successfully* parsed.

The obvious solution here is to integrate all the subsequent steps into the same grammar and/or to reuse the iterators (so the iterator's stored backtrack buffer still contains the characters you need).

---

### Demonstration / Proof of Concept

Here is a version that parses open tags in a loop

```
while (boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parse(begin, end, gr, sk, tag)) {
    std::cout << "============\nParsed open tag '" << tag.m_name << "'\n";
    for (auto const& p: tag.m_attribute)
        std::cout << p.first << ": " << p.second << "\n";

    count += 1;
    tag.clear();
};

std::cout << "Next symbol: ";
std::copy(begin, end, std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout));
```

And it prints:

```
============
Parsed open tag 'object'
cName: bool
cVersion: 1
vName: bool
============
Parsed open tag 'value'
Next symbol: 0</value>
        </object>
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fe306f4c7be85b1c)</kbd>**

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <map>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

// The class implements a XML tag storing the name and a variable number of
// attributes:
struct Tag {
    typedef std::string name_type;
    typedef std::string value_type;

    typedef std::pair<name_type, value_type> attribute_type;
    typedef std::map<name_type, value_type>  list_type;

    // Clear all information stored within the instance:
    void clear() {
        m_name.clear();
        m_attribute.clear();
    }

    std::size_t m_indent;  // The tag shall be / is indented by m_indent number of tabs.
    name_type m_name;      // Name of the tag.
    list_type m_attribute; // List of tag attributes.
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Tag, m_indent, m_name, m_attribute)

// This class implements the grammar used to parse a "XML" begin tag.
// The expected format is as follows: <name a="xyz" b="xyz" ... N="xyz">
template <typename Iterator, typename Skipper> struct tag_begin : qi::grammar<Iterator, Tag(), Skipper> {
    tag_begin() : tag_begin::base_type(m_tag) {
        m_string     = *qi::char_("a-zA-Z0-9_.:");
        m_attribute  = m_string >> '=' >> qi::lexeme['"' >> m_string >> '"'];
        m_attributes = *m_attribute;
        m_tag        = '<' >> -qi::int_ >> m_string >> m_attributes >> '>';

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((m_string)(m_attribute)(m_attributes))
    }
  private:

    // The following variables define the rules used within this grammar:
    qi::rule<Iterator, Tag::attribute_type(), Skipper> m_attribute;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Tag::list_type(), Skipper> m_attributes;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Tag(), Skipper> m_tag;
    // lexemes
    qi::rule<Iterator, Tag::name_type()> m_string;
};

bool beginTag(std::istream &stream, Tag &tag) {
    // Ensure that no whitespace characters are skipped:
    stream.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);

    typedef boost::spirit::istream_iterator It; 
    typedef qi::rule<It> skipper_type;

    skipper_type sk = qi::space | qi::cntrl;
    tag_begin<boost::spirit::istream_iterator, skipper_type> gr;

    It begin(stream), end;

    int count = 0;
    while (boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parse(begin, end, gr, sk, tag)) {
        std::cout << "============\nParsed open tag '" << tag.m_name << "'\n";
        for (auto const& p: tag.m_attribute)
            std::cout << p.first << ": " << p.second << "\n";

        count += 1;
        tag.clear();
    };

    std::cout << "Next symbol: ";
    std::copy(begin, end, std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout));

    return count > 0;
}

int main() {
    std::stringstream s;
    s << R"(
        <object cName="bool" cVersion="1" vName="bool">
            <value>0</value>
        </object>
    )";

    Tag t;
    beginTag(s, t);
}
```

¹ (which is strictly forward-only and cannot be repeatedly dereferenced)

Comment: Added a proof-of-concept demo [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fe306f4c7be85b1c)